# VSTS Build Task hangs in case of creating new process inside the target power-shell script

Tags: c#, powershell, tfs, azure-devops, exe

My custom build task hangs only in VSTS build
in my target power-shell script, I create a new process that executes some .exe file
but once I start the process it hangs and never ends (only in VSTS, locally in windows it works fine)

I tried to change the .exe to .dll and it works fine in both VSTS and windows

Here is the sample for the code
1- In case of exe (which hangs)

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("App1.dll")
$psi = New-object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo 
$psi.CreateNoWindow = $true 
$psi.UseShellExecute = $false 
$psi.RedirectStandardOutput = $true 
$psi.RedirectStandardError = $true 
$psi.FileName = "App2.exe"
$psi.Arguments = @($arguments)
$process = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process 
$process.StartInfo = $psi
```

-Start "App2.exe"

```
 [void]$process.Start()
```

-Hangs after I call start and goes into an infinite loop here

```
$output = $process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() 
$process.WaitForExit() 
Write-Host $output
```

-Assume I'm calling function1 inside "App1.dll"

```
[App1.NameSpace.Class]::Function1()
```

2- In case of changing the "App2.exe" to "App2.dll" (works fine)

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("App1.dll")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("App2.dll")
[App2..NameSpace.Program]::Main(@($arguments)
[App1.NameSpace.Class]::Function1()
```

I've tried all agent pools and still hangs every time but still couldn't figure out what's the issue when I try to use .exe file or when I try to create a new process, because it works fine while I'm testing locally from windows power-shell

Comment: Could you add related failed part build log  when your build triggered? Better with `system.debug=true` enabled. Besides, are you using hosted build agent or local build agent?

Comment: Actually there's no fail, it goes into infinite loop or gets stuck
any hosted agent fails(gets stuck), the local works fine

Comment: Sorry for the not clearly description, I know local works fine. With the host build agent which provided by Microsoft is hard to troubleshoot the issue, Since you do not have the access to log on the hosted agent. You could try to [deploy your own self-hosted](agents. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/agents/agents?view=vsts#install), you could run your build on your own agent and remote to agent to check if some process hangs up cause the infinite loop.